# jquery datepicker - dynamic altfield issue

Tags: jquery

I have multiple datepickers on a page... all seems to be working fine except I the altfield part...

Is something like this possible??

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function(date){ return [(date.getDay() == 1 || date.getDay() == 4), ""] },
        showOn: "button",
        buttonText: "Book now...",
        showWeek: true,
        firstDay: 1,
        onSelect: function(date) { 
            $(this).parent().find('.selecteddate').prepend("Date: " + $(this).parent().find('.datepicker').val() + " - <a href='javascript:;' class='cleardate'>clear date</a>"); 
            $(this).parent().find('button').hide();
        },
        dateFormat: "DD, d MM, yy",

        altField: $(this).closest('div').find('.datepickeralt'),

        altFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        navigationAsDateFormat: true,
        minDate: 0,
    });

    $(".cleardate").live('click',function(){
        $(this).closest('div').find('.datepicker').datepicker("setDate", null);
        $(this).closest('div').find('.datepickeralt').val("");
        $(this).closest('div').find('button').show();
        $(this).parent().html("");
    });

});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can do exactly that, you just need to instantiate the date pickers with a [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) loop, like this:

```
$('.datepicker').each(function() {
  $(this).datepicker({
    altField: $(this).closest('div').find('.datepickeralt')
  });
});
```

This way inside the [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) `this` refers to what you want, each individual date picker, then finding *its* alt field.  [You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/BhzE5/).

Comment: @Tom - Here's the demo implemented with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/BhzE5/1/