# JQuery Date Picker Dynamic altField

Tags: jquery, uidatepicker

I have a set of dynamic pages, with jQuery datepicker fields on them.

I would like the nice cosmetic date written back to the user, however the input field that is used to submit the data is hidden.

I saw [This other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811883/jquery-datepicker-altfield-issue/15024631#15024631) which all worked great, until I tried to implement the buttonImage method, so that my field can be hidden.

[jsfiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/wcndave/jYk6j/)

```
    Date: <input type="text" class="datepicker">&nbsp;
<input type="text" class="datepickeralt" size="30"/>


    $(function () {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
        });
    });


    $('.datepicker').each(function() {
        console.log(this);
      $(this).datepicker({
        altField: $(this).closest('div').find('.datepickeralt')
      });
    });
```

At first I thought "this" was attached to the image instead of the field, however if you take the first function out or not, the console logging is exactly the same.

Comment: "Any help appreciated" is unnecessary; please don't include it in your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this :

```
$(function () {
$(".datepicker_sep, .datepicker").each(function(){
$(this).datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    altField: $(this).parent().find('.datepickeralt')
});
})
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jYk6j/3/

Comment: this works great, although I had to be a little more complex in the end and only write the cosmetic version if the class warranted it, so I also used elements of the version below.